# Last update: OR.SE at INFORMS

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, events

Here's how you can help promote OR.SE at INFORMS in Seattle next week:

- **OR.SE badge tags:** These will say "OR Stack Exchanger." You can pick them up at the INFORMS Center in the exhibit hall (in the same rack as tags for session chair, blogger, etc.). Wear it proudly!
- **OR.SE flyers:** There will be a stack of postcard-sized OR.SE flyers (preview below) at the INFORMS Center. Please take a handful of them and distribute them to your friends and colleagues at the conference. If there aren't enough on display, conference staff should have more they can give you. Feel free to take enough to hand out at your next conference too.
- **Stack Exchange stickers:** Stack Exchange is sending us some stickers to hand out, too. They'll just have the standard SE logo. I'll have these with me and am happy to give you a handful to hand out. Ping me on [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94323/operations-research) if you want to arrange to meet up so I can give you some. (I arrive Monday morning.)

In addition, there will be a slide promoting OR.SE in the deck of **"welcome slides"** that play on a loop at the beginning of certain sessions, like plenaries.

Unfortunately there won't be an INFORMS social-media meetup, and we didn't arrange an OR.SE-centric meetup, but if you see an OR.SE friend (or someone with the badge tag), say hello!

**Many thanks** to Stack Exchange and to INFORMS for paying for the printing costs and making this swag happen.

Here's what the flyers will look like:

*Front*:

[image]

*Back*:

[image]

Feel free to put the flyer image in your slides if you want to make a pitch for OR.SE during your presentation, too. :)

See you in Seattle!