# How was OR.SE received at INFORMS?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, events

Thanks to some excellent initiative by members of our community, there was a concerted effort to socialize OR.SE at INFORMS 2019 ([1](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/271/491), [2](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/242/491), [3](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/243/491), [4](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/254/491), [5](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/247/491)).

**How was OR.SE received by those you interacted with?**
**Are there any actionable takeaways for the OR.SE community?**

Comment: Not really an answer but INFORMS put up a [video of the awards](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52267685#52267685), which sort of gives you a *feel* for some of the atmosphere; other portions of the conference were nothing like that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

INFORMS was good. It's a big conference and the OR.SE presence was there, but somewhat diffuse.

- The conference had "OR Stack Exchanger" badge ribbons looked good:

[image]

- Stack Exchange printed up a bunch of postcard-sized flyers, which were prominently on display in the INFORMS Center in the exhibit hall:

[image]

I handed out a bunch of these—maybe other folks did too?

- They also sent a bunch of Stack Exchange stickers, but unfortunately they were delayed in transit and didn't arrive until just before the conference ended:

[image]

**If anyone wants some postcards or stickers, let me know!** I have a lot of them and am happy to mail them to you if you want to bring them to your next conference.