# Should OR.SE plan outreach for other professional events?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, events

OR.SE conducted outreach at [INFORMS 2019](https://www.informs.org) thanks to initiative by members ( [1](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/254/491),[2](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/271/491),[3](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/242/491),[4](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/243/491),[5](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/247/491)). This seems like a [productive effort](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/273/491) if members are already attending a professional event.

**Is there any interest replicating this to other professional events?**

Examples include<sup>1</sup>:

- 8–11 Dec 2019: [Winter Simulation Conference (WSC)](http://meetings2.informs.org/wordpress/wsc2019/)
- 30 May–2 Jun 2020: [Institute of Industrial and Systems Engineers (IISE)](https://www.iise.org/annual/)

<sub>1.  Not exhaustive. I'm sure there are other potential events.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I definitely agree we should promote the site at as many conferences as we can. I have a bunch of OR.SE flyers and SE stickers and would be happy to mail some to anyone who wants to distribute them at conferences. Just send me an email.

Answer (score 5):

I think that's a great idea. There are also local chapters of INFORMS in different cities (a list of US and some international chapters can be found [here](https://www.informs.org/Communities/INFORMS-Chapters)) that have events. That, plus hopefully help from [student chapters](https://www.informs.org/Communities/INFORMS-Student-Chapters), can be another avenue for outreach.

Answer (score 4):

- INFORMS has a [Calendar of Events](https://www.informs.org/Meetings-Conferences/INFORMS-Conference-Calendar/(cc_report)//(cc_year)/2019/(cc_month)/4) listing Operations Research related events.
- COMS has listings for: [Informatics](https://www.conference-service.com/conferences/computer-science.html) or [Mathematics](https://www.conference-service.com/conferences/mathematics.html), or browse by country ([USA](https://www.conference-service.com/conferences/us/index.html)).

  There are similar sites such as: AllConferenceAlerts.com: [Correlation](https://www.allconferencealert.com/correlation.html), [Mathematics](https://www.allconferencealert.com/mathematics.html), [Mathematics and Statistics](https://www.allconferencealert.com/mathematics-and-statistics.html), [Representation Theory](https://www.allconferencealert.com/representation-theory.html), etc. and [World Conference Calendar](http://www.worldconferencecalendar.com/component/option,com_conference/page,show_category/catid,4/Itemid,0/expand,0/order,1/). You can also restrict your search by country on those sites.
- Societies, such as [AMS](https://www.ams.org/meetings/calendar/mathcal), The Fields Institute for Research in Mathematical Sciences ([Fields](http://www.fields.utoronto.ca/activities/workshops)), National Council of Teachers of Mathematics ([NCTM](https://www.nctm.org/events/)), etc.
- Wikipedia has a webpage listing: [Mathematics Conferences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Mathematics_conferences).